# I changed computers and I am getting a bunch of namespace errors when trying to build project?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, namespaces

I change computers and copied my website files over to my new machine. Now my website will not build. I am getting a bunch of errors that gridview1 is not declared or may be inaccessable due to its protection level. Also getting error on every page:

Warning 2   Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Expressions' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.   C:\Users\user\Desktop\website\frmArchivedReports.aspx

Comment: Check that your project references are all good (there will usually be a little yellow exclamation sign next to it if it isn't). It's possible you've got a missing DLL somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Expressions` namespace is part of the `System.Web.Extensions.dll`, so verify that this is still valid in the solution on your new computer.

My guess is the path of this DLL is different between the two computers.

Answer (score 1):

Also check the target framework version and make sure you have that version of .NET framework installed on the new PC

Answer (score 1):

I was running in same issue, Copied Project from One PC to another PC and Started getting all “namespace of type specified in the imports doesn't contain any public member” Errors.

I fixed by changing the Project Properties->Compile->Advanced Compile Options->Target Framework value from .Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile to .Net Framework 4.0

Hope This Helps

/*Happy Coding */